# Define a Region where a disequation is satisfied for all values of a variable

Tags: mathematical-optimization, regions, inequalities

I'm having a problem with Mathematica.

I have a large and complicate system of 3 inequalities in 3 variables, let's call them x,y,z.

Now, I can't use reduce to solve it exactly.

There is a way to define the region of x,y such as the system is satisfied for all z?

I tried

```
ImplicitRegion[ForAll[z,z :elem: Reals, sys],{x,y}]
```

of course, it doesn't work.

I need this region for a minimization process.

Thanks for everyone that will help.

EDIT: Here is an example

```
sys = {};
AppendTo[sys, x^2*y*(1 + z^2 + x*z^4) >= 0];
AppendTo[sys, z^2*y*x^2 <= 0];
AppendTo[sys, z^4 + y^3 + x^8 >= 0];
```

Now I want to define the region of the plane x,y where the inequalities hold for all the z. For example, the point (x,y)=(1,1) is in this region, while (x,y)=(-1,1) is not.

Of course, this is just a toy problem, you can use reduce and find the solution, but in my real problem, I can't use it. This is just to give you some ideas.

Another thing, if it is too hard to find the region of the whole plane x,y, you can restrict to a bounded region for example [-1,1]x[-1,1].

Comment: Please provide a concrete example.

Comment: I've edited as you asked. Hope it is enough.

Answer (score 1):

```
sys = ForAll[z, And @@ {
     x^2*y*(1 + z^2 + x*z^4) >= 0,
     z^2*y*x^2 <= 0,
     z^4 + y^3 + x^8 >= 0
}];

reg = ImplicitRegion[Resolve[sys, Reals], {x, y, z}]

(* example minimization *)
Minimize[x^4, {x, y, z} ∈ reg]
```

The system can be reduced further:

```
Resolve[sys,Reals]
(* y == 0 || (x == 0 && x^8 + y^3 >= 0) *)
Reduce[%]
(* y == 0 || (y >= 0 && x == 0) *)
```

Comment: Thanks, but why Resolve would work while Reduce doesn't? ( There are so many things that I don't know...)

Comment: @Eso Resolve takes out the quantifiers. See the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Resolve.html)  _attempts to resolve expr into a form that eliminates ForAll and Exists quantifiers_

Comment: First of all, Thanks. I tried but it doesn't work for my system, it gets blocked at the resolve part. So I think we can't play with a toy system, so I want to post the real system but it is large, and copy and paste don't work.  When I will understand how to do it I will post it.

Comment: @Eso - `Reduce` works. `Simplify@Reduce@sys` evaluates to `(x == 0 && y >= 0) || (y == 0 && x != 0)` which is equivalent to what @flinty obtained since the excluded point `{0, 0}` in the second alternative is covered by the first alternative.

Comment: When I said that reduce doesn't work, I mean on the real system that I have and not on the toy problem that I proposed just as an example. Of course, it works for the toy problem, I said it into the post, and flinty shows us that works better after resolve.